# Mongoose Object.save() only working if called twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know this sounds rediculess...
In my function `index()` I retrieve a Model for a specific `collectionName` promted by commandline parameters. After a async AXIOS API call a `saveToDB(response, model)` is called.

```
export async function index(collectionName) {
  let model = getModelForCollection(collectionName)

  await axios.get(url)
            .then(resp => {
                saveToDB(resp.data, model)
                    .then(saved => {
                        ...
                    })
            })
}

async function saveToDB(response, model) {
    
  const word = new model({response})
  await word.save()
     .then(() => {
         console.log("saved")
     })
}
```

So basicly this should easily work, but the strange thing is. This does only! work, if I save another document prior to calling `saveToDB()` in `index()`. Changing the function to;

```
export async function index(collectionName) {
  let model = getModelForCollection(collectionName)

  let word = new model({word: 'WORT'})
  await word.save().then(() => {
      console.log("saved")
  })

  await axios.get(url)
            .then(resp => {
                saveToDB(resp.data, model)
                    .then(saved => {
                        ...
                    })
            })
}
```

Is there anything strange going on I am not aware of? Excuse my super unspecific question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should read the docu: https://mongoosejs.com/
or search for related questions. I guess its not a mongoos problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you consuming and "awaiting" the `Promises` at the same time. Why don't you keep it simple like this:

```js
export async function index(collectionName) {
  try {
    let model = getModelForCollection(collectionName)

    let resp = await axios.get(url);
    let saved = await saveToDB(resp.data, model);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(error);
  }
}

async function saveToDB(response, model) {
  try {
    const word = new model({ response });

    let writeStatus = await word.save();
    console.log("saved");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(error);
  }   
}
```

Comment: I guess you are totally right. I don't have to use .then all the time... What do you mean by consuming and awaiting?
Nevertheless I don't think this resolves my problem.

Comment: Its just my way of telling "consumes" means using `.then()` style and "awaiting" means using `async\await`.

Comment: Can you post whats inside `getModelForCollection` function?

Comment: Ok i guess now i understood your problem. I think `response` is an array i.e., you are trying to write multiple documents using `save`. You should use `insertMany` instead: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany